# Is it possible to modify the right-click menu for the tray network connection?

Tags: windows, windows-8.1

I often want to get to the connection properties for a LAN adapter or Wifi connection, but for whatever reason Microsoft gives only 2 options in Windows 8.1 - "Troubleshoot problems" and "Open Network and Sharing Center".

I want to be able to jump straight to "Control Panel\Network and Internet\Network Connections"->Status or for a particular connection from the tray.  Is this possible via some registry editing or a 3rd-party app?

[image: Wi-Fi Status page]

Answer (score 1):

I found a way after reading [this tutorial](http://www.7tutorials.com/how-pin-special-windows-shortcuts-taskbar). It can turn you straight forward to `Connection Status` with just one click. Follow below steps:

1. Create shortcut to `Connection status` by go to `Network connections`, right click on a network adapter, select `Create shortcut`. Windows will notice that it cannot create shortcut here, create in desktop instead --> select yes.
2. Create another shortcut:

   Right-click to empty area --> select `New` --> `Shortcut`. On opened windows, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd> to the input box. Then add word `explorer` before input string. This is the magical word ([see here](http://www.7tutorials.com/how-pin-special-windows-shortcuts-taskbar)).

[image]

Click `Next`, rename the shortcut as you want. Click `Finish`.

'3. Right-click to the last created shortcut, select `Pin to taskbar`.

Now, you can go straight to `Connection status` as you want by click shortcut on taskbar.  Default icon of the last created shortcut is folder icon, you can change it by right-click --> on `Shortcut` tab, click to `Change icon` button.

**Updated.**

Answer (score 0):

I won't say it is not possible to change the right click context menu but I am assuming it would involve lot of work.

Workaround:
Right click on the network icon -> Open network and sharing center -> change adapter settings -> right click on whatever network adapter you are connected with -> create shortcut -> it will say "Windows can't create a shortcut here. Do you want the shortcut to be placed on the desktop instead? Yes/No" -> click "Yes".

You would be able to access the above menu by double clicking the shortcut icon.

Hope it helped.